Is 2.5 hours a tight connection at Singapore Changi Airport?
I am arriving at Singapore Changing airport at 3 pm with Emirates Airline from Dubai and going to Bali with AirAsia 5.30 pm. Is two and a half hours sufficient time?

Is this on one ticket? So no self connect?

I don’t think Emirates and Air Asia interline. So most probably a self-transfer, which makes it quite risky, especially as AirAsia uses T4 qui is not directly connected to the other terminals. Do you have any checked bags? What is your citizenship?

Thank you very much and I will book another flight.

As I believe Emirates and Air Asia don't interline, this must be a self-transfer (two separate tickets).
If you have checked bags, this means you have to get through passport control, wait for your bags, go to T4, and check-in again. And check-in/baggage drop for your onward flight closes 1h before departure, so in effect, if your incoming flight is on time, you only have 1h30 to:

Deplane (may take a while if you're at the back of a full 380)
Make your way to passport control
Queue and get through
Wait for your bags
Go through customs
Go up to departures
Exit to the bus stop for the public shuttle to T4
Wait for the bus (can be up to 26 minutes!)
Get to T4 (10 minutes)
Get to the check-in area for your flight
Queue and check-in/drop your bags

After that you will still need to:

go through exit passport control
go through security
get to your gate before it closes

But usually the critical part is getting to the check-in/bag drop counter in time.
I'm not even certain you can be sure to do it even without a delay (lots of variables there), and if anything goes wrong, especially the incoming flight being delayed, all bets are off. That flight is usually on time, but delays do happen.
Remember that if you don't check in in time for your onward flight, you will be considered a no-show, and your ticket will be cancelled. You will need to book and pay for a new ticket, at last minute prices (which can easily be 5 times more expensive). Since this is the last flight of the day (unless you fly via Kuala Lumpur, quite a detour), you'll also have to book and pay for a hotel, meals, and transfers to/from the hotel.
Finally, it also means that if your citizenship does not give you visa-free entry into Singapore, you will need a visa.
If you don't have checked bags and you can get a mobile boarding pass for your second flight, your chances are better (no passport control, no waiting for bags, using the airside shuttle, can skip bag drop in T4...), but there's still little margin, and the same warnings about missing your connecting flight apply.
It is usually recommended to have at least 4 hours between two flights when self-transferring, possibly a lot more depending on the circumstances (especially whether the connecting flight is frequent and cheap, even at the last minute).

Thank you very much and I will book another flight to Bali.

Even if assuming all goes well, that's quite a tight connection time especially given that it isn't on the same itinerary and/or airline.
Next time if you're gonna be presented with such tightness, make sure they are of same airline [group] and same itinerary so any disruption like missing onward flight due to late arrival, will surely be c/o the airline concerned.
For example, I went for Singapore Airlines to London from Manila via Singapore. I believe we arrived at Changi ~11am and then SQ 321 to LHR departs around 1pm. That's tight but I won't worry because they are under the same booking and same airline, because like 99.00-99.99% of the time they will have you ultimately end up at your final destination without further cost to you.

Two days ago the OP said in a comment on the first answer that they would book another flight. This answer adds nothing of value to the existing answers, IMHO.
